# How do I copy to a range, rather than a list, of columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am looking to append several columns to a dataframe.

Let's say I start with this:

```
import pandas as pd

dfX = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4],'B': [5,6,7,8],'C': [9,10,11,12]})
dfY = pd.DataFrame({'D': [13,14,15,16],'E': [17,18,19,20],'F': [21,22,23,24]})
```

I am able to append the `dfY` columns to `dfX` by defining the new columns in list form:

```
dfX[[3,4]] = dfY.iloc[:,1:3].copy()
```

...but I would rather do so this way:

```
dfX.iloc[:,3:4] = dfY.iloc[:,1:3].copy()
```

The former works! The latter executes, returns no errors, but does not alter `dfX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
dfX = pd.concat([dfX, dfY], axis = 1)
```

It returns

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1   5   9   13  17  21
1   2   6   10  14  18  22
2   3   7   11  15  19  23
3   4   8   12  16  20  24
```

And you can append several dataframes in this like pd.concat([dfX, dfY, dfZ], axis = 1)

If you need to append say only column D and E from dfY to dfX, go for

```
pd.concat([dfX, dfY[['D', 'E']]], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Here's what I ended up with:

dfX = pd.concat([dfX, dfY.iloc[:,1:3]], axis = 1)